# Multiple lookups

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

If I had a lookup table called fares below for example

- District.      Price1.      Price2.    Price3.     Price 4
- SN1.           30.00.       35.00.     40.00.     44.00
- SN2.           25.00.       30.00.     33.00.     39.00

Is there. Way to do multiple price lookup. The sendable DE will contain the district as a lookup. What I want to do is pull each price in to an email in separate tables. Is this doable?

Is there away to do random lookups

Any examples would be great

Answer (score 1):

You can return multiple fields with LookUpRows(). This returns a row set that has all match rows, and every field on the data extension. It must be unpacked with the Row() function (most of the top just the first row is used) and Field() functions.

http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/#section_31

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/#LookupRowsCS

Lookups cannot be random. If you are trying to pull a random value in for each district (say for district SN1, you want to provide either 30, 35, 40, or 44 as a cost), I would suggest sending multiple emails after segmenting your subscribers. Both groups and data extensions support random splits. Sending random data to a single group prevents any sort of useful tracking analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @mobo about the lookups.  I have some examples on my blog, [here](http://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/).

Regarding retrieving random rows from a data extension (not for building a send audience), there is a [Random()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#Random) AMPScript function.  You could calculate TotalRows and RowNumber columns in your data extension with a [Query Activity](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) and then do a [LookupRows()](http://wiki.memberlandingpages.com/010_ExactTarget/020_Content/AMPscript/AMPscript_Syntax_Guide/Data_Extension_AMPscript_Functions#LookupRows(S1.2c_S2.2c_S3)) using a specific row number calculated with the Random() function.  Your lower bound would be 1 and your upper bound would be the TotalRows value.  You'd need to retrieve the TotalRows value in a lookup on its own.

Just out of curiosity, what's the business case for selecting a random DE row inside an email?

Comment: Thanks guys I have managed to pull the values in using multiple lookups. Another question - i send an email every two weeks but don't want to look up the same value but pull the next value in the step is this possible. For example if I pull price1 this week and in two weeks time I would like to pull price2. I know I can do this manually by changing price1 to price2. But wanted to know if I can automate it without someone changing it each time